# Proving an element belongs to field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I am unsure of questions asking to prove that an element belongs to a field extension. Here is an example:

> Prove that $\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}  }  )$

$\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Let:

$x=\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}} \implies (\frac{x^2-11}{3})^2-13=0 \implies x^4-22x^2+82=0$

Let:

$x^2=y \implies y^2-22y+82=0 \implies y= \frac{22 \pm \sqrt{22^2-4\times82}}{2}=11 \pm \sqrt{11^2-82}=11 \pm \sqrt{39}$

So it appears that $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}  }  )$, is this correct?

Comment: to see if $a \in \mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{b})$ (where $a,b$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$) you look at the minimal polynomial of $b$, and then what ? (I don't understand what you are trying to do at the end)

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but my idea was to try and find a minimal polynomial, whose roots contained terms of $\sqrt2$ in.. I am unsure

Comment: if you are unsure that's a bad sign : the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}})$ or over what field ? and personnally I'd try to find the other roots of $x^4-22 x^2 + 4$ and use them to define $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}})$ as a vector $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space and see if $\sqrt{2}$ lies in it

Comment: I don't know if it really helps but there is a mistake : it should be $ (\frac{x^2-11}{3})^2-13=0 \implies x^4-22x^2+4=0$.

Comment: That's why I asked for help. I would like to know the correct method which I can then learn from @user1952009. It seems like my initial idea is right: to find the polynomial $P$ of which $x=\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}$ is a root. Then find the other roots, and if these include radical roots, $r_1, ..., r_n$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}})=\mathbb{Q}(r_1, ..., r_n)$. Then see if $\sqrt{2}$ is one of $r_i$ then it belongs to the field extension. Is that ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $$\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: So the answer is yes. How did you arrive at this equality, or was it immediately obvious? For example, in an exam i would like to be able to manipulate such expressions. Any tips?

Comment: @thinker : the answer is yes because $\sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}}$ is also in the field, and with what C.Dubussy wrote : $\sqrt{11+3\sqrt{13}}+\sqrt{11-3\sqrt{13}} = \frac{6}{\sqrt{2}}$ (or something like that)

Comment: @thinker : I tried to write $11+3\sqrt{13}$ as a square to cancel the first radical. I wanted $3\sqrt{13}$ to be my double product so I computed $(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{2}})^2$ and see that I get the answer. So the basic trick for this kind of problem is to complete the square.

Comment: @C.Dubussy Thank you, I am going to try this technique with another question and see how I get on